# navigationBar Background Image on iPad with iOS 5 in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uinavigationbar, landscape, ios5

Im struggling with this for a while and i cant find anyone with a related issue. 
My problem is that the background image that gets loaded on for the landscape mode on the iPad its not the correct one (it loades the portrait version of the image). 
On the iphone or iPod it work as its supposed to.

The code im using on my AppDelegate file is the following:

```
if ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0 ) {
    // Create resizable images
    UIImage *gradientImageP = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    UIImage *gradientImageL = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"header-Landscape"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImageP
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImageL
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green: 0 blue:0  alpha:1]];
}
```

The problem is in this line?

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImageL
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

My images names are the following:

- header-Landscape~iphone.png
- header-Landscape@2x~iphone.png
- header-Landscape~ipad.png
- header~iphone.png
- header@2x~iphone.png
- header~ipad

Edit: Screenshots of the problem on the navigation bar:

- iPhone portrait:
  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/200/iphoneportrait.png/
- iPhone landscape:
  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/193/iphonelandscape.png/
- iPad portrait:
  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/ipadportrait.png/
- iPad landscape:
  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/200/ipadlandscape.png/

Anyone with this issue? 
Im open to ideas on how to solve this, tkz

Comment: Are you expecting the ~ipad to be loaded on an iPad instead?  I haven't seen this convention before.  Do you have some code that automatically does it for you?

Comment: Yes, im expecting the filename with the ~ipad to be loaded on that device. Im using this kind of names on the other images of the app and they load correctly. Anyway, ive tried various types of filenames for all the files but, for the navBar, this problem remains :\

Answer (score 3):

Just use this Code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad-menubar.png" ] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1):

Does appending ~iPad work for the portrait mode?

It isn't for me. Do you also have to specify ~iPhone to get it to work?

I got a separate image working for the iPad by doing

```
- (void)customizeAppearance {

    if ([[UINavigationBar class]respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {

        // Create resizable images for iphone
        UIImage *navbarImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg_portrait"] 
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        UIImage *navbarImage32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg_landscape"] 
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

        // Overide for iPad
        // In theory navbar_bg_landscape~iPad should work
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            //use iPad specific image extending last pixel for landscape mode
            navbarImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bg_portrait~iPad"] 
                                      resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 767, 0, 0)];
       }

        // Set the background image for *all* UINavigationBars
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarImage44 
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        // Never called on iPad, used for landscape on iPhone
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarImage32 
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
    }
}
```

But for landscape mode it uses the portrait image and repeats the last pixel column to complete the missing portion, so no good for your problem although this may be of use for other readers.

Comment: Appendng ~iphone and ~ipad works great on the iphone version, but not on the ipad.

Comment: Ive tested your code with that if condition for the ipad and it doesnt work for the portrait version, heres the screenshot: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/3118/semnomeq.png As i said, its maybe a simulator issue?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to manage the appearance method working for the iPad with rotation. Even though the frame of the navigation bar is resized correctly, the graphic doesn't change. In the end I hooked the `viewWillAppear:animated` and `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` methods of all my controllers to simply call `setBackgroundImage:` with the correct version on the iPad. Ugly, but works.

It's possible this might be a bug worth reporting to Apple. The names of the defines themselves are also confusing, `UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone` doesn't make sense on iPads and your default app orientation could be landscape!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
UIImage *gradientImageP;
UIImage *gradientImageL;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    //use iPhone specific images
    gradientImageP = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"header~iphone.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    gradientImageL = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"header-Landscape~iphone.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    //use iPad specific images
    gradientImageP = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"header~Landscape~ipad.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

}
```

Comment: Already tried by using (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad), same problem :\

Comment: I was taught to think that when something doest work, probably its because theres something wrong with my code, but in this situation, i think the problem is that this new class from iOS 5 its to "new"

Comment: I just thought of something ... you don't need a "landscape" image for  the iPad ... because the UINavigationBar is the same height in both Landscape and Portrait on the iPhone.

Comment: I think you need to set the portrait image to your ipad landscape image for the ipad idiom.

Comment: The problem with that implementation is that if i use the image header~Landscape~ipad.png on the portait mode, the title of the App wont stay on the middle of the screen. If i shrink the image, it looks ugly. Ill launch the update to my app with the "buggy" code i posted, maybe it will be resolved by the ios 5.0.1